# How to add class member to vector and use it correctly?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this class

```
class Employee {
string name;
vector<Employee> subEmployee;

Employee(string name, vector<Employee> subEmployee) {
    this -> name = name;
    this -> subEmployee = subEmployee;
}
vector<Employee> getSubEmployee() {
    return this -> subEmployee;
}};
```

and I create several objects and connect them,

```
Employee yunfei("yunfei",{});
Employee yuqi("yuqi",{});
Employee yuwei("yuwei",{});
Employee aona("aona",{});
Employee shang("shang",{});
yuqi.addNewEmployee(yuwei);
yuqi.addNewEmployee(aona);
yunfei.addSubEmployee(yuqi);
```

Then I want to check how many subemployee yunfei has, so I use:

```
yunfei.getSubEmployee();
```

The result shows vector contains yuqi,
however, when I try to use:

```
yunfei.getSubEmployee()[0].getSubEmployee();
```

I just get an empty list, but when I use:

```
yuqi.getSubEmployee();
```

I get the correct answer, so I want to know why that happened.

Comment: `std::vector::push_back` (which I'm assuming `addNewEmployee` uses internally) creates a copy of the object in the vector. You want the vector to store pointers to the actual employees instead.

Comment: You're passing and returning everything by value, so when you add elements to `yuqi` it has no effect on the vector inside `yunfei`.

Comment: Also I notice you're passing/returning everything by value. In addition to performance issues this will probably lead to problems down the road. Do some research on passing/returning objects by reference and const reference.

Comment: You're calling functions that do not exist, mate.

Comment: `vector<Employee>` is not permitted by Standard C++ there. Even if your compiler appears to support it, it might have odd behaviour.  The template type for `vector` must be complete. A class cannot contain a vector of itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most people have mentioned, you want to make use of references to ensure you are always *referencing* the same employee.

```
class Employee
{
    using EmployeeList = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Employee>>;
    std::string mName;
    EmployeeList mSubEmployees;

public:
    Employee(const std::string& name, const EmployeeList& subEmployees = {}) 
        : mName(name), mSubEmployees(subEmployees)
    {}

    const EmployeeList& GetSubEmployees() const { return mSubEmployees; }
    const std::string& GetName() const { return mName; }
    void AddSubEmployee(const std::shared_ptr<Employee>& employee) { mSubEmployees.push_back(employee); }
}

// I can make these employees first.
auto yuwei = std::make_shared<Employee>("yuwei");
auto aona = std::make_shared<Employee>("aona");
auto shang = std::make_shared<Employee>("shang");

// I can construct these employees using existing employees
auto yuqi = std::make_shared<Employee>("yuqi", { yuwei, aona });
auto yunfei = std::make_shared<Employee>("yunfei",{ yuqi });

// I can add new subs now
yunfei.addSubEmployee(shang);

// Even brand new employees
yunfei.addSubEmployee(new Employee("Aesthete");
```

These employees only exist int the context where you declared them. All other employees now only hold reference to the others. You could now iterate the employee tree using recursion.

```
void PrintEmployeeTree(const Employee& e, int level = 1)
{
    for (const auto& employee : e->getSubEmployees)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(level, '-') << employee->GetName() << std::endl;
        PrintEmployeeTree(employee, level+1);
    }
}

PrintEmployeeTree(yunfei);
```

Should give you something like this:

```
-yunfei
--yuwei
---yuki
---aona
--shang
--Aesthete
```

Try to use references wherever makes sense. Same goes for const. Notice how even the employee name is return by reference. Look at where all the references I have made are, and how many copies they have avoided. This will ensure you're always working with the same set of data.

Comment: This isn't a very good design; for example if someone writes `{ Employee e("e",{});  list.AddSubEmployee(e); }`, or `list.AddSubEmployee(Employee("e",{}));` then the list will contain a dangling reference.   It'd be better to use shared_ptr here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "match your example" as the original example did not have the possibility of dangling references

Comment: The example was intended to show the use of references primarily, but sure, I've changed it to use ptrs.